# изменить регистр заглавных букв всех слов в строке, работая только со строкой, без исп массива и т.п

Tags: javascript

У нас есть строка аля "Вася петя маша таня", между слов пробелы, нужно сделать буквы имен заглавными, при помощи toUpperCase(), indexOf() и for/while. Другими методами пользоваться нельзя. Без массивов.

Индексы пробелов в цикле я нахожу при помощи такой конструкции:

```
var str = "Ослик Иа-Иа посмотрел на виадук"; // ищем в этой строке
var target = "Иа"; // цель поиска

var pos = -1;
while ((pos = str.indexOf(target, pos + 1)) != -1) {
  alert( pos );
}
```

Дальше пытаюсь через str.slice(...) + str[pos+1].toUpperCase() получить всю строку с изменными буквами - не получается )

Еще раз повторюсь, мы не пользуемся массивами, у нас есть строка и цикл.

Comment: Что значит не получается?) Приведите полный пример, как вы пытаетесь реализовать.

Comment: Ну и топай по строке, запоминая предыдущий символ... если предыдущий пробел, а текущий нет - toUpperCase текущий. А уж как ты собираешься отличать имена от не-имён, я лично фиг знает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, можно даже без indexOf обойтись:

```js
let str = "мама мыла раму, а папа - маму";
let space = ' ';
let newStr = str[0].toUpperCase();

for(let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
  if(str[i] == space) {
    newStr+=str[i+1].toUpperCase();
  }
  else {
    newStr+=str[i+1];
  }
}

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, в результате без индекса написал такое:

```
var str = "вася петя маша таня";
n = str[0].toUpperCase()
x = 1

while (x < str.length){
  if (str[x] == ' '){
    n += str[x] + str[x+1].toUpperCase()
    x+=2
  } else {
    n += str[x]
    x++
  }
}
```